# C# how to return to previous statement

Tags: c#

Hello im wondering how to return to previous statement in C#

For example i want to show user readline again when he filled it wrong and when he will do it right it will show him the next line of code/statement(in this exam. Console.WriteLine("Hi"))

How could i do it?

```
int num;
string prvnicislo;
prvnicislo = Console.ReadLine();

while (true)
{
    if (int.TryParse(prvnicislo, out num))
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(prvnicislo);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not int, try it again:", prvnicislo);
        prvnicislo = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Hi");
```

Comment: You are going to have to think about that `while (true)` loop and how it affects your program.

Comment: You can add a `break` statement after the `Convert` line to break out of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the following code snippet

```
int num;
string prvnicislo;
prvnicislo = Console.ReadLine();

while (true)
{
    if (int.TryParse(prvnicislo, out num))
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(prvnicislo);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not int, try it again:", prvnicislo);
        prvnicislo = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Hi");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

I think this will work:

```
 int num;
 string prvnicislo =  Console.ReadLine(); 
 while (!int.TryParse(prvnicislo, out num))
 {
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not int, try it again:", prvnicislo);
     prvnicislo = Console.ReadLine();
 }
 Console.WriteLine("Hi");
```

Notice that there is not necessary to use Convert.ToInt32 because if the parsing has been succeed the TryParse method will assign the parsed int value to num.

Comment: This is what im looking for!! Thank you

Comment: @JakubStanek Accept his answer as correct if helped you !

Answer (score 0):

if this can be of any help

```
string prvnicislo = String.Empty;
bool isEntryWrong = true;

do
{
    Console.Write("Enter data: ");
    prvnicislo = Console.ReadLine();

    int num;
    if(int.TryParse(prvnicislo, out num))
    {
        isEntryWrong = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not int, try it again:", prvnicislo);
    }
} while (isEntryWrong);

Console.WriteLine("Hi")
```